# What is the role of deliverer and his free will in the law of karma

Tags: karma, free-will

In discussions about karma they talk about free will of individual, the subject who is at the receiving end but not about the deliverer who may be involved.

Suppose say, I was about to be subjected to cruelty due to my bad  karma, was I thrust into a situation by the universe near some beings who are about use their free will to commit that act? Do they receive bad karma?

If beings just stopped being bad or in larger numbers then who will deliver punishment as there will be no one left to subject you to harsh cruelties, then bad karmas of beings stop getting cancelled?